# How to use Twilio.Device to call a number

Tags: twilio, twilio-click-to-call

How to call to a phone number using Twilio.Device?

I am doing the click to call feature for my widget.
I am able to get the Capability token required in setting up the Twilio.Device. I am able also to connect the Twilio.Device to twilio by setup function provided in client javascript library.

What can I use to call a number using Twilio.Device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its been a while since I played with it, but looking back at the code then once you have the token and are connected to Twilio it's just a case of setting the number you want to call and then initiating the call. Something like this:

```
      document.getElementById('button-call').onclick = function () {
        // get the phone number to connect the call to
        var params = {
          Caller: document.getElementById('phone-number').value
        };

        console.log('Calling ' + params.Caller + '...');
        Twilio.Device.connect(params);

  };
```

You have to make sure your token allows outgoing calls. My token.php file contains the following:

```
$capability = new ClientToken($TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, $TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN, 'ttl=20');
$capability->allowClientOutgoing($TWILIO_TWIML_APP_SID);
$token = $capability->generateToken();
```

I think this is all fairly standard stuff from the quickstart files. I only had a quick go with it, but I don't remember it being complicated. Have fun!

Comment: You also need to build a server side TwiML app that will receive a webhook when you make the call. You can then extract the `Caller` parameter from the request and use [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) and [`<Number>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number) to forward the call onto the number.